# Azure Function Access CloudBlobContainer from HttpTriggerFunction

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

Very, very new to Azure Functions and getting very frustrated.

All I want to do is execute on a 'get' request from a HttpTriggerFunction and return stream content from the CloudBlobContainer.

I really don't see why this is so hard. Just trying to host a SPA using Azure Functions.

Something like this

```
  public static class UIHandler
{
    [FunctionName("UIHandler")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, 
        TraceWriter log, 
        CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        var stream = await container.GetBlockBlobReference({Infer file name from request here}).OpenReadAsync();

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StreamContent(stream)
        };

    }
}
```

When I try to run this I get the following error.

> Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'UIHandler.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter
>   'container' to type CloudBlobContainer. Make sure the parameter Type
>   is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g.
>   ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
>   method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

I'm using Azure Functions 2. I can't see from the web how to setup the browsing extensions for this. Iv'e also looked into Input and Output bindings. I don't understand what makes a parameter input or output bound when your using C# that only seems to exist in the JSON.

Do I need to corresponding JSON file ? If so what is it called where does it go.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Blob Storage Input Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input). The very first sample there shows how to read blob stream, just replace Queue Trigger with HTTP trigger, e.g.

```
[FunctionName("UIHandler")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{name}")] HttpRequest req,
    string name, 
    TraceWriter log, 
    [Blob("samples-workitems/{name}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream stream)
{
    log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request for {name}.");

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StreamContent(stream)
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, except I had to copy the stream to a MemoryStream and set that as the content. It's seem Azure disposes the Stream that was passed in automatically. It's a shame as this will restrict the size of files that can be sent.